# Python super() pass in *args

Tags: python, super

I am confused about the convention of passing `*args` in `super().__init__()` in python inheritance.
I understand the need to use keyword arguments `**kwargs` so the required arguments can be taken by the class in CRO if needed, but why there's also a `*args`?

Example:
Suppose Sneaky is used as part of a multiple inheritance class structure such as:

```
class Sneaky:
   def __init__(self, sneaky = false, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.sneaky = sneaky

class Person:
    def __init__(self, human = false,  *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.human = human

class Thief(Sneaky, Person): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

t = Thief(human = true, sneaky = true)
print(t.human)
# True
```

So what if we have below instead aka remove the *args?

```
class Sneaky:
   def __init__(self, sneaky = false, **kwargs):
        super().__init__( **kwargs)
        self.sneaky = sneaky

class Person:
    def __init__(self, human = false, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.human = human

class Thief(Sneaky, Person): 
    def __init__(self,  **kwargs):
        super().__init__( **kwargs)

t = Thief(human = true, sneaky = true)
print(t.human)
# True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing in `*args` means that you can initialize your `Thief` like

```py
>> x = Thief(True, False)
>> x.human
False
>> x.sneaky
True
```

This is confusing to read, and difficult to trace with multiple inheritance, but it could be useful. Maintaining this capability means you could do

```py
sneaky = (True, False, True,)
human = (True, False, False,)
thieves = [Thief(*args) for args in zip(sneaky, human)]
```

This is a bit contrived, but I think it illustrates why you might want to allow positional arguments.

If you do want to remove the `*args` and not support positional arguments,  you can exclude them from `Sneaky` and `Person` as well by adding `*,` after `self,`.

```py
class Sneaky:

    def __init__(self, *, sneaky=False, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sneaky = sneaky

class Person:

    def __init__(self, *, human=False, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.human = human
```

This does not put all positional arguments in an un-named `*`. This will raise a `TypeError` if you try to provide a positional arugment.

Comment: Thanks that's really clear to understand! Sorry i didn't get enough reputation to upvote but I mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

In first case following code will output `True`.

```py
t = Thief(True, True)
print(t.human)
# True
```

But in second (without `*args`) - it will raise exception:

```py
t = Thief(True, True)  # arguments without keywords
print(t.human)
# raises
# TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'd like to upvote to this answer as well but I haven't got enough reputation. Will grow my repu and come back to upvote!